# Nested Span Elements Effecting Formatting and JS Output

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've been working on a site that highlights a Tibetan phrase and it's English counter part when the user hovers over it. This bit of jquery works to do that function [jsfiddle example of working code](http://jsfiddle.net/6BH27/1/).

```
<p><span title="extensive">ཆེན་པོ་</span><span title="Entering the Middle Way">དབུ་མ་ལ་འཇུག་པའི་        </span><span title="explanation">རྣམ་བཤད་</span><span title="The Illumination of the         True Thought">དགོངས་པ་རབ་གསལ་</span> <span title="Here begins">བཞུགས་སོ</span>་།།</p>

<p><span title="བཞུགས་">Here begins</span> <span title="དགོངས་པ་རབ་གསལ་">The Illumination of the True Thought</span>, an <span title="ཆེན་པོ་">extensive</span> <span title="རྣམ་བཤད་">explanation</span> of <span title="དབུ་མ་ལ་འཇུག་པའི་">Entering the Middle Way</span>.</p>
```

However, when I need to format the text, to bold or change font size for example, [jsfiddle example of nonworking code](http://jsfiddle.net/vajra108/7zDp2/) the nested spans seem to create a conflict and the highlight function ceases to work properly.

```
<p><span style="font-size: 24px;"><span title="extensive">ཆེན་པོ་</span> <span title="Entering the Middle Way">དབུ་མ་ལ་འཇུག་པའི་</span> <span title="explanation">རྣམ་བཤད་</span> <span title="The Illumination of the True Thought">དགོངས་པ་རབ་གསལ་</span> <span title="Here begins">བཞུགས་སོ</span>་།།</span></p>

<p><span style="font-size: 20px;"><span title="བཞུགས་">Here begins</span> <span title="དགོངས་པ་རབ་གསལ་">The Illumination of the True Thought</span>, an <span title="ཆེན་པོ་">extensive</span> <span title="རྣམ་བཤད་">explanation</span> of <span title="དབུ་མ་ལ་འཇུག་པའི་">Entering the Middle Way</span>.<span></p>
```

Any ideas on how I can go about fixing this.  Ultimately, I'd like to implement as a wordpress quicktag or shortcode or possibly even creating a plugin to handle this but I have no working knowledge of php.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
vajra108

Comment: I don't understand the need of nesting span for this.

Comment: I see you answered my question below. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Be sure to check out the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restrict the `:contains` search to only the span elements that contain just the text, not the span elements used for formatting.  In your non-working jsFiddle, you can do that by just adding the `[title]` to them as in this:

```
$('span[title]:contains("'+$(this).attr('title')+'")').addClass('highlight');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        $('span[title]:contains("'+$(this).attr('title')+'")').removeClass('highlight');
    }
);
```

But, I'd probably suggest you actually use a class name for a less fragile specification.  That way you'd only be searching exactly the span elements you want to search and no others.

Modified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cj2G5/

FYI, your whole issue would get less complicated if you used class names and CSS for formating too rather than inline span tags with CSS styles on them.

Comment: Thank you, I will implement.

Comment: How would I go about implementing class names and css to format everything?

Comment: @user3288210 - See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/WkPcN/ for CSS formatting with no inline styles and a somewhat simpler javascript implementation too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that you are nesting spans. In the code below you are targeting the span which contains the required text and highlight it, but you can see that the style span also contains all the text so it is highlighting the style span.

```
 $('span:contains("' + $(this).attr('title') + '")').addClass('highlight');
```

What you can do is, you can remove the style span and style the paragraph instead (
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/7zDp2/1/)**).

**NOTE:** Avoid using inline css.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help.